# Setting Microprofile active profile using mp.config.profile not working in Liberty

Tags: open-liberty, microprofile, eclipse-microprofile-config

Im currently trying to run a microprofile open liberty project as a jar.

java -jar myapp.jar -Dmp.config.profile=test

The app runs but is not picking the configuration values from microprofile-config-test.properties
instead is using values from microprofile-config.properties

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm guessing you're probably not using one of the beta versions of Open Liberty where the `mpConfig-2.0` feature was introduced (but is still in beta).   What is your Open Liberty version and your feature set.   Are you using Maven?

Answer (score 1):

## Enabling MicroProfile Config 2.0 Feature

First, you enable in your server.xml via:

```xml
    <featureManager>
        <feature>mpConfig-2.0</feature>  
        <!-- 
            Or enable all MicroProfile 4.0 features via:
            <feature>microProfile-4.0</feature>   
          -->
    </featureManager>
```

## Installing GA version of Open Liberty

### Default version

By default, `liberty-maven-plugin` will install the latest version of Open Liberty.

### Installing a specific GA version

You can install a specific version of Open Liberty (e.g. version **21.0.0.3** which contains the GA support for MicroProfile 4.0 features such as MicroProfile Config 2.0) via liberty-maven-plugin config:

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>io.openliberty.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <assemblyArtifact>
                <groupId>io.openliberty</groupId>
                <artifactId>openliberty-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>21.0.0.3</version>
            </assemblyArtifact>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

### Installing a beta version of Open Liberty with liberty-maven-plugin

**UPDATE:**  (I originally posted this answer when the MicroProfile Config 2.0 feature was still in beta, but for reference I'll move this to a new section below.)

Here is how to install a specific version of the Open Liberty runtime beta, using the liberty-maven-plugin:

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>io.openliberty.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <assemblyArtifact>
                <groupId>io.openliberty.beta</groupId>
                <artifactId>openliberty-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>21.0.0.3-beta</version>
                <type>zip</type>
            </assemblyArtifact>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you the issue was resolved by following your recommendation I was using mpconfig 1.4